# how to use flann_index function in python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, python-2.7

I am a newbie to OpenCV in python.

I have OpenCV 2.4.0 installed with python 2.7.

Can anyone please explain what are the arguments of this function? A simple example will be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has an example for this function: [find_obj.py](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/samples/python2/find_obj.py#L27)

Documentation does not explain python signatures but the parameters can be mapped to the [C++ documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html).